# Short story in Analog/Asimov's about far future godlike human, seduction, betrayal?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been trying to find a short story in Asimov's or Analog from the 1990s or later (to at least 2010) about the following:

- extremely far future from present-day Earth, maybe a million years
- a single bodiless human maintains a museum of past human artifacts floating in outer space, from a child's doll to large battleships and even the devices that humans used to become incorporeal telekinetic godlike immortals thousands of years ago
- the rest of humanity is a gestalt that the main character has rejected
- the story has a female bodiless human meeting the caretaker, claiming she was rejected by the gestalt because of her beliefs
- female seduces the male into a mini-gestalt
- male is unaware that she is destroying his museum artifacts during the seduction, the reason she was rejected, she is actually desperate to join the gestalt, this is what the others told her to do
- story ends with the non-corporeal male rebuilding his artifacts telekinetically from the atoms left behind; the female left him to rejoin the gestalt

Again, not a main story or even what the magazine used for a cover story.  I do not remember any details of the title or author.